# Problem in drush configuration with wamp server 64 bit

Tags: drush

I am trying to enable drush for wamp server 64 bit.

I have configured all things with youtube videos and it seems it must be ok but when I run drush via cmd console, I see this error message :

**PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './php_gd2.dll' - The
specified module could not be found.**

My operating system is windows 7 64 bit. so I have installed Wamp server 64 bit version. PHP version is 5.5.12 and apache version is 2.4.9

I don't know what is the reason of this problem. I checked my php.ini
extension path is ok. also I can see "php_gd2.dll" file inside extension folder.

so why I see this error that says specified module could not be found?

Answer (score 2):

PHP for Apache and CLI have different configuration files, so check if you're using the right one.

To identify which php.ini is used by drush, run `drush status`:

```
$ drush status 
PHP executable         :  /path/to/bin/php                         
PHP configuration      :  /path/to/php.ini
```

then edit that file and check if you've the right extensions specified.

Alternatively check using `php` command, for example:

```
$ php -i | grep php.ini
```

<sup>Note: In case `grep` command is not found, replace with the with `find`.</sup>

If you still have a problem, possibly that your DLL library was compiled for the wrong version of PHP. So either use the one included with WAMP, or download the right one specifically for that version of PHP.

Also double check that your command-line `php` points to the right place (WAMP folder):

```
$ where php
$ which php
```

which should give you `C:\WAMP\PHP\bin`-like path, if it's not, update your system `PATH` variable in advaned system settings.

Finally to check if your GD2 library is loaded, check by:

```
php -r "phpinfo();" | grep gd2
```

<sup>Note: The `grep` can be replaced with `find` on Windows if you don't have Linux command utilities installed.</sup>

Comment: I am using wamp on windows 7 64 bit. You mentioned run "drush status" but I have written drush command cause this error. indeed drush command doesn't work at all.
But I checked php.info. result is >> Configuration File (php.ini) Path : C:\Windows  and Loaded Configuration File  : C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini. does this information help?

Comment: @Mehrdad201Missing `gd2` library normally shouldn't prevent from `drush` running, apart of the issue described in [here](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/1616), as I had similar issue with `memcached`.

Comment: @Mehrdad201The `php.ini` from `phpinfo();` should help, but your still points to Apache path, so make sure you run `phpinfo();` from the CLI (not Apache), or use `php -i` instead to find out the config file. Unless they're pointing to the same file, which is a bit weird.

Comment: Dear @kenorb, can you tell me how can I run phpinfo from CLI (not apache) ?

Comment: @Mehrdad201 Run PHP from the command-line (in `cmd.exe` console), not the web browser, e.g. `php -r "phpinfo();" | find "php.ini"`.

Comment: I did it. I went to php via cmd. it was located at C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12  then I executed php -i command. The result has a lot of lines but I can't find any php.ini in output texts

Comment: Also I executed this command php --ini via cms when I was in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12   - the result is 

Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

Comment: @Mehrdad201 So `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini` is the right file to change, comment out the loading of `gd2` extension, as you probably not need that for drush.

Comment: maybe drush doesn't need gd2 plugin. but if I disable it so drupal sites that work with gd2 plugin won't work correctly.

Comment: @Mehrdad201 Your question is about how to enable `drush` which is command-line only and PHP configuration for command-line and Apache are 2 different things. So anything you disable for PHP CLI, won't affect any of your sites, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do. If you're focusing on PHP CLI, edit that config for CLI only and remove that non-working plugin, it won't do anything with your sites.